# integrating two systems through email

Tags: c#, c++, email

I want to integrate our bug tracker system and our Support system through emails.

The bug tracker can kick out an email on every change to bugs/features.  I want to download those emails, parse them and create a formatted email that the Support system can understand (ie the subject could be "Issue #4128 fixed").

What is the simplest way to accomplish this using C++ or C#?

Answer (score 1):

Martin, I'd say there's no "simplest" way to do this.  The easy part is downloading the e-mail.  (If that's what you need help with, say so and I'll post some C# code that does this.)  How you parse the e-mail depends on the format of the message.

For instance, if the body of the message contains the data you want to provide to your support system, your approach will be different than if that data is included as an attachment to the message.

With more information, I'm sure we can be more helpful.

Comment: Do you wish to download mail from a POP3, IMAP, or Exchange server?